# I want to solve this system of equations by iterating one of the initial conditions

Tags: python, process, iteration

I Want to solve a system of three differential equation, changes the initial conditions

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp 

#__________________________Condiciones Problema ________________________
#Constants that are use in the problem
Yxs    = 0.06
Yxp    = 0.06
Umax   = 0.24
Ks     = 1.6
Cpm    = 100
n      = 2    
#Function to solve de ODE

def fermentation_process(C,t):
    Cx , Cs , Cp = C
    U      = (Umax*((Cs/(Ks+Cs))*(1-(Cp/Cpm)))**n)
    rx     =  U*Cx
    rs     = -(1/Yxs)*(rx)
    rp     =  (1/Yxp)*(rx)
    dCx_dt = rx 
    dCs_dt = rs 
    dCp_dt = rp
    return [dCx_dt,dCs_dt,dCp_dt]
#________________________Initial condition_____________________
Cx0   = 0.1
Cp0   = 0
#________________________Iterable intial Condition______
```

I save the initial conditions in a function to use this function in a bucle for

```
#Fuction to save the inintial conditions
def ini(Cs0):
    return np.array([Cx0,Cs0,Cp0])

t_lim = (0,60)
Cs0   = 0
```

Bucle for evaluate the variable inintial condition Cs0

```
for i in range(5):
    Cs0 += 10
    sol = solve_ivp(fermentation_process, ini(Cs0), t_lim)
    Tiempo = sol.t
    concentraciones = sol.y 
    figure, axis = plt.subplots()
    plt.plot(Tiempo, concentraciones[0])
    plt.plot(Tiempo, concentraciones[2])
plt.show()
```

The error that I obtain is:

> File "C:/Users/Paula/.spyder-py3/Sin título0.py", line 50, in
>   fermentation_process   Cx , Cs , Cp = C
>
> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object

Answer (score 0):

Please update the below function (as we cannot assign an array to multiple variables)

```
def fermentation_process(C,t):
    Cx , Cs , Cp = C[0], C[1], C[2]
```

(or)

```
def fermentation_process(C,t):
    Cx = C[0]
    Cs = C[1]
    Cp = C[2]
```